Challenges with Creating and Redirecting to the New Empty Case with One Click
We are attempting to streamline the process of creating a new empty Case in Salesforce with a single click. Below are the different approaches we’ve tried, the challenges we encountered, and the code we’ve implemented. We’re seeking advice on how to resolve these issues or recommendations for alternative solutions.
First Approach: URL Button to Call a Flow
We created a custom button on the Case List Page with a URL (/flow/Create_Empty_Case) to call a flow. The flow is designed to create a new empty Case and then redirect to a screen element. The screen contains a custom Lightning Web Component (LWC) that uses the NavigationMixin to navigate to the newly created Case record.
Problem: The LWC successfully captures the record ID of the new Case, but when invoked from the Case List Page, the NavigationMixin fails to perform the redirection to the Case record page. It appears that NavigationMixin doesn’t function correctly when used within the context of the Case List View.
Code:
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class NavigateToRecord extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;

    connectedCallback() {
        if (this.recordId) {
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__recordPage',
                attributes: {
                    recordId: this.recordId,
                    objectApiName: 'Case', 
                    actionName: 'view'
                }
            });
            console.log('Navigating to Case record page...');
        } else {
            console.error('No recordId received for redirection.');
        }
    }
}

Second Approach: Visualforce Global Action Button
We created a global action button using Visualforce that calls an Apex controller to create the new Case. After the Case is created, the controller redirects the user to the Case record page.
Problem: While this solution works in terms of creating and redirecting to the Case, a blank popup with a disabled Save button appears on the page. We were unable to find a way to prevent this popup from appearing, which results in a poor user experience.
Visualforce Code:
<apex:page Controller="CreateEmptyCaseController" lightningStylesheets="true" action="{!saveCase}">
</apex:page>

Apex Controller:
public with sharing class CreateEmptyCaseController {
    public Case newCase { get; set; }

    public CreateEmptyCaseController() {
        newCase = new Case();
        newCase.Status = 'New';
    }

    public PageReference saveCase() {
        try {
            insert newCase;
            PageReference newCase = new PageReference('/' + newCase.Id);
            newCase.setRedirect(true);
            return newCase;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}

Third Approach: Visualforce Button on Case List Page
We created a Visualforce button on the Case List Page, which invokes an Apex controller to create a new Case and then redirect to the newly created record. This solution initially seemed promising, as it successfully creates the new Case and redirects the user.
Problem: After redirecting, the Case List Page gets stuck on the Visualforce page. Each time the page is refreshed, it triggers the creation of a new Case, causing an infinite loop of Case creation. The page doesn’t navigate back to the original Case List View, making the solution unusable in its current form.
Visualforce Code:
<apex:page standardController="Case" recordSetVar="cases" extensions="CreateEmptyCaseController" action="{!saveCase}">
</apex:page>

Apex Controller:
public with sharing class CreateEmptyCaseController {
    public Case newCase { get; set; }
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController controller;

    public CreateEmptyCaseController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
        newCase = new Case();
        newCase.Status = 'New';
    }

    public PageReference saveCase() {
        try {
            insert newCase;
            PageReference newCase = new PageReference('/' + newCase.Id);
            newCase.setRedirect(true);
            return newCase;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}

Fourth Approach: Custom Lightning Component in a Flow
We built a custom Aura Lightning Component that is used as a Quick Action in a flow. The flow creates a new Case, and once the Case is created, the Aura component should handle the redirection to the newly created Case record page using $A.get('e.force:navigateToSObject').
Problem: Although the component is invoked after the flow creates the Case, the redirection does not happen. The component is unable to navigate to the new Case record page, leaving the user on the flow screen without transitioning to the new Case record.
Aura Component Code:
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction, lightning:availableForFlowActions">
   <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
</aura:component>

<design:component>
   <design:attribute name="recordId" label="Record ID" />
</design:component>

Controller Code:
({
    invoke : function(component, event, helper) {
        var record = component.get("v.recordId");
        var redirect = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        redirect.setParams({
            "recordId": record
        });
        redirect.fire();
    }
})

Question:
Given the approaches we’ve tried, we are still facing issues in creating a new Case with one click and redirecting the user to the new Case record page.
Key issues:

Redirection failures from the Case List Page when using NavigationMixin in LWC.
Visualforce popups appearing when using global action buttons.
Infinite case creation loops when using Visualforce buttons on the Case List Page.
Aura component redirection failing in the flow context.

Is there a more reliable method to achieve this functionality? What are we missing, or how can we resolve these issues?
Thank you in advance for any suggestions or guidance!
